# Backreference preg_replace with commas in subject

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can you please help me find the preg_replace syntax so i can duplicate the price where it is missing?
The subject is:

```
...nomaterwhat13124123,"321,00",,nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat12321,"322,20","134,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat1321,"211,00",,nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat31313,"241,00",,nomaterwhat
```

My output want to be:

```
...nomaterwhat13124123,"321,00","321,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat12321,"322,20","134,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat1321,"211,00","211,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat31313,"241,00","241,00",nomaterwhat
```

I tried

```
preg_replace("(\W+),,nomaterwhat$", "$1,$1,nomaterwhat", $string);
```

Comment: This looks like generic CSV format, have you considered a simple loop using [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/str_getcsv) and replace values at that point?

Comment: Hmmm nope... To be honest i didnt :P

Comment: That isnt all but yes it always ends with nomaterwhat

Comment: @JamieBicknell can you give me an example with how i can parse it with str_getcsv and replace the prices in each line?

Comment: Any issues/questions with provided answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring more complex cases this should do:

```
$result = preg_replace('/,"(\d+,\d{2})",,nomaterwhat/', ',"$1",$1,nomaterwhat', $string);
```

Comment: I noticed tha some values didnt get replaced. Something like this... `,"144,00",,nomaterwhat` :S It looks like the same... Weird

Answer (score 2):

If you use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) you can do something like this:

```
$data = "CSV VALUES";

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $temp = str_getcsv($line);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($temp, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Then you can put these into an array like so:

```
$data = "CSV VALUES";
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$output = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $temp = str_getcsv($line);
    $temp[5] = ($temp[5] == '') ? $temp[4] : $temp[5];
    $output[] = $temp;
}
echo '<pre>' . print_r($output, true) . '</pre>';
```

Replace `$temp[5]` with the place that the 2nd price should be.

Comment: That's cool, technically it doesn't answer your question as it's not regex, but it's useful to know other ways to do it.

Comment: i ll try to use it because maybe will solve some other issues... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your regex. 
 1. No delimiter
 2. No `m` modifier so `$` is the end of the string, not line.
 3. `\W+` is a non `a-z`, `0-9`, and/or `_` so you wouldn't have gotten the
    money value there anyway.

Try this out:

```
$string = '...nomaterwhat13124123,"321,00",,nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat12321,"322,20","134,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat1321,"211,00",,nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat31313,"241,00",,nomaterwhat';
echo preg_replace("/,(\"\d+,\d{2}\"),,nomaterwhat$/m", ",$1,$1,nomaterwhat", $string);
```

Output:

```
...nomaterwhat13124123,"321,00","321,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat12321,"322,20","134,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat1321,"211,00","211,00",nomaterwhat
...nomaterwhat31313,"241,00","241,00",nomaterwhat
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hE2zQ7/1

PHP Demo: http://ideone.com/OanPN1